# In Python 3 efficient way to convert my list of ID's into string split by using CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.5 what is the efficient way to convert the **list** called `id_list` below into a string split by `,`?

**Expected return output:** (string list of ids CSV with no brackets)

```
?ids=2,6"
```

**Actually output:**

```
ids={2, 6}"
```

I have tried the following:

1) `return "?ids={}".format(str(id_list))` = `{5, 6}` - Incorrect

2) `return "?ids={}".format(*id_list)` = 2 = Incorrect

3) `return "{}/?tags={}".format(str(id_list).replace('[','').replace(']',''))` = `{5, 6}` = Incorrect

5) `return "?ids={}".format(" ".join(map(str, id_list)))` = `5 6` = Incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return "?ids={}".format(",".join(map(str, id_list)))`